# Remapping a used engine

Tags: performance, wear

I appreciate that a performance increasing remap is likely to increase the rate of wear and tear on certain components inside an engine bay.

Is remapping an engine that already has 50k miles on the clock going to have any additional impact that needs to be considered over remapping an engine which has < 1k miles on the clock?

If this is different across different engine types, let's consider a 2L turbo petrol engine that you get in the VAG S/R line models.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a broad question, and I'm a Subaru geek, not a VAG geek, but I'll share my never-humble opinion.

Any flash that increases performance obviously increases stresses.  A *proper* remap with careful logs and monitoring might *improve* the longevity of any performance enhancement.

Then again, you never get something for nothing (despite the billion-dollar bolt-on industry claims) and the harder you push, the less time you will enjoy the pushing...

In the end, the "wear" factor is fairly linear, assuming the internals and bearings are solid.  You can drink a fresh pint of beer quickly, or drink a half pint slowly.  It's a matter of choice.

Now if you have a rod main that's marginal, a performance reflash might be catastrophic.  The engine line and mileage are only rough guestimates...  There's no knowing how a 1K motor was treated, or how the 50K motor was treated.  If I was starting from absolute scratch and *building* the motor, I would probably choose the 1K block.  If I'm swapping in a 50K long block, I'd leave the flash stock and log and monitor a while to get a feel of how old she feels, before I start adding boost or changing AFR tables.

Again, bottom line is that apples-apples a seasoned block and internals will be fine if they were treated properly to begin with.  Younger components *might* have more wear margin (more beer to drink) but it's all a guess unless you are willing to do a complete teardown and rebuild.  What is absolutely certain is that NO motor will withstand a tune that goes lean and hot to gain performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Steve, you're right, it is sadly quite a broad question.

You've made some very interesting points which I think I'm  going to start googling!

Comment: Key is to get a tune that truly reflects your mods.  No point in an "Off the Shelf" reflash if you haven't changed exhaust, intake, injector size, or other mods which potentially increase the VE (volumetric efficiency) of the engine.  It's a pump, and we want to make it pump better.  Unfortunately, there's aftermarket "hotrod" solutions that suggest you plug in and gain 50hp.  These usually make the gains by going lean, which works but shortens lifespan dramatically.  Despite rumors there's not a single OEM that sells cars with 50hp in reserve if you only load and "unlock" the right flash.

Comment: I would agree with the most part of what you've said. I will differ with you a little on the "lock and load" flash idea. Most of today's turbocharged cars, to include your Subies, have relatively low stock boost levels. The VAG engines which the OP talks about run at about 5psi (IIRC). You can easily get and extra 50hp out of them by raising the boost levels without making them go lean/hot. Everything in the engine will take it without issue as VAG designed them much better than what they produce. I don't know why VAG did it that way, but it is what it is.

Comment: Totally agreed, but I will differ with you a little on your little difference....  Stock subie is around 7psi manual wastegate.  In 4 mintes I could adjust linkage to 10psi, and not change a single map.  BUT, the OEMs are no idiots, and don't  know I'm a fool going to put 87 RON from Jack's Discount  while blasting across Arizona.  For stock scooby TD04, increasing boost a few psi takes you to the next lower efficiency locus on the compressor map. Now you have more heat, knock, risk. (Or ECU backs out the "50hp").VAG is probably more conservative [German], but my philosophy remains the same.

Comment: @BadAtMaths -- Paulster knows tons more about turbo VAG then I do, so as long as your willing to pay for 93 pump and get a proven flash, and follow all the installation instructions -- I see know reason why 50hp is an issue on a otherwise stock 2 liter.  1K or 50K.  My condemnation of the "lock and load" set was not for flashes from proven tuners that do their homework, it was aimed at the cheaper set or the buddy that "borrows" your flash without doing homework. Roughly speaking, the *next* 50hp is a LOT of homework and $$$.

Comment: Thanks both of you, very interesting discussion, going to mark this as the answer as I don't think I'm going to get much more from anyone else!

Comment: We have an addiction not unlike any other, except it costs more and requires a lot more study!